# Change File Extension dialog box not responding to selection

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I was attempting to rename a file and change its extension from `.notes` to `.txt` to after pressing <kbd>return</kbd>. I get these options:

[image]

and then I pressed <kbd>tab</kbd> and chose `Use .txt` option. I then pressed <kbd>return</kbd> expecting that the option that I had chosen through the <kbd>tab</kbd> button would be respected. However the file didn’t change the extension. Is there another key we have to press instead of enter after selecting our choose through the <kbd>tab</kbd> key?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Tab</kbd>  doesn't change a modal dialog selection.

I've been fighting with it for some time, but the best way to deal with it is to just go to Finder prefs > Advanced & uncheck "show warnings before changing an extension"

There is a key command, but once you find it, it prevents that warning, whatever the preference is set to. So you can’t test it again… grr… [it’s <kbd>cmd</kbd> + something between <kbd>Y</kbd> & <kbd>P</kbd>… I was trying them all to find it…]

Answer (score 0):

**To select**, press <kbd>**space**</kbd>.

---

However, if <kbd>tab</kbd>ing doesn't work to move the selected option, you will need to go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Change the `Full Keyboard Access...` to `All Controls` (see bottom of this picture):

(it looks like you've already done this):

[image]